# Find the loci of the circle $(\!{\rm C}'\!)$ .

Tags: circles, rotations

> In one plane $Oxy$, given the circle $(\!{\rm C}\!): x^{2}+ y^{2}- 2x+ 4y- 4= 0$ around point $O$ for $60^{\circ}$ and it maps in the circle $(\!{\rm C}'\!)$. Find the loci of the circle $(\!{\rm C}'\!)$.

Firstly, we let ${\rm M}(x, y)\in (\!{\rm C}\!), {\rm M}'({x}',{y}')\in (\!{\rm C}'\!)$. We always have the following system of equations
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
{x}'= x\cos\alpha- y\sin\alpha\\ 
{y}'= x\sin\alpha+ y\cos\alpha
\end{matrix}\right.$$
or
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
{x}'= x\cos 60^{\circ}- y\sin 60^{\circ}\\ 
{y}'= x\sin 60^{\circ}+ y\cos 60^{\circ}
\end{matrix}\right.$$
so
$$x= \frac{1}{2}{x}'+ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}{y}'$$
$$y= \frac{1}{2}{y}'- \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}{x}'$$ 
Secondly *https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2F2a%2Bsqrt(3)%2F2b)%5E2%2B(-sqrt(3)%2F2a%2B1%2F2b)%5E2-2(1%2F2a%2Bsqrt(3)%2F2b)%2B4(-sqrt(3)%2F2a%2B1%2F2b)-4%3D0*. So, how can I prove the given system of equations as follow ?
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x'= x\cos\alpha- y\sin\alpha\\ 
y'= x\sin\alpha+ y\cos\alpha
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Finally, I need to the helps! Thanks for all the nice comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The question was:**

*Circle $\left ( C \right ): x^{2}+ y^{2}- 2\,x+ 4\,y- 4= 0$ $(1)$ in plane $Oxy$ around point $O$ for $60^\circ$ and it maps in circle $(C').$ Find $(C').$*

**Solution**

$\left ( C \right ): x^{2}+ y^{2}- 2\,x+ 4\,y- 4= 0$ rewrites as $$(x-1)^2+(y+2)^2=9,$$ thus the center is $S(1,-2)$ and the radius $r=3.$ Through a rotation, the circle is transformed in a circle $(C')$ with equal radius $r=3$ and the center  $$S'(1\cdot \cos 60^{\circ} -(-2)\sin 60^\circ,\,1\cdot \sin 60^\circ+(-2)\cos 60^\circ)=S'(1/2+\sqrt3,\sqrt3/2-1). $$

From this $\left ( C' \right ): \left(x-\frac{1+2\sqrt3}{2}\right)^2 + \left(y-\frac{\sqrt3-2}{2}\right)^2=9.$

Answer (score 1):

We have $x^{2}+ y^{2}- 2x+ 4y- 4= 0 \therefore {x}'^{2}- (\!2\sqrt{3}+ 1\!){x}'+ {y}'^{2}- (\!\sqrt{3}- 2\!){y}'- 4= 0$. Using twice
$$ax^{\,2}+ bx+ c= \frac{(\!2ax+ b\!)^{2}+ 4ac- b^{2}}{4a}\,\therefore\,\frac{1}{4}(\!-\,2{x}'+ 2\sqrt{3}+ 1\!)^{2}+ \frac{1}{4}(\!-2{y}'+ \sqrt{3}- 2\!)^{2}- 9= 0$$